# Citrix xenapp server looking to wrong IP address for the lic server after a reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, licensing, citrix, xenapp

Had an application server reboot this morning, after which, instead of pointing to the proper IP address for the license server [which is set through our computer unfiltered policy], it it looking at the farm's primary STA/XML broker's IP.  So it is now sitting in it's grace period.

No other server in the farm is having this issue.  The server can ping out to the license server, there are no custom load evaluators or other Citrix policies that are preceding my comp unfiltered.

I have been researching on where this value is stored [Citrix 6.0, server 2008 r2] but anything I come across, I just do not see where the license server info is kept.

And nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be defined in either Group Policy (With the Citrix Add-In) or the Citrix Policies themselves. It sounds like maybe you're not applying the policies to this server.

These settings are registry based. I'm not in a position to do it for you, but you could search the registry of a working server for the license server name or IP address (One of which would have been defined by the administrator) and then compare and contrast with your broken server.

Comment: Yes, the citrix computer policies are not applying as the IMA key is missing under HKLM\Software\policies\citrix\ , which houses the licensing server info.  Hoping a quick gpupdate /force and reboot will clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

## Empty Citrix Policy Cache

I think it is worth trying to empty the Citrix policy cache directories. (Even though I don't completely understand the background.)

From [CTX132102: *Troubleshooting Process for Printing Issues with Auto-creation Failure and Citrix Print Manager Crashing*](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX132102): (Archived [here](https://archive.is/etpW4).)

> [...] If the policy is still not applying, complete the following tasks:
>
> 1. Open the `C:\ProgramData\Citrix\Group Policy` folder and delete all items in the `Group Policy` folder. Open a Command window and run the `gpupdate /force` command to add contents to the folder with the new Group Policy information from Active Directory and Citrix.
> 2. Open the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Citrix` folder, and remove all hives with a session number. This is a dynamic key and does not affect any existing sessions on the server. This ensures that all new sessions receive the new group policies on the server.
> 3. Restart the `Citrix Group Policy Engine` service, and you will now notice that new sessions populate the registry hive with the correct policies applied.

From [CTX134961: *XenApp Policies not Applying Correctly*](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX134961): (Archived [here](https://archive.is/1EKKo).)

> If deleting the policy folders on the Microsoft Domain Controller (s) does not resolve the issue, clear the locally cached policies on each XenApp Server in the farm followed by running a `gpupdate /force` on each server.
>   The locally cached policies are located in the following locations on the XenApp Server: (Delete the files and folders in each location but not the actual folder that contains them). 
>   [...]
>   `C:\ProgramData\Citrix\GroupPolicy`
>   [...]
>   `C:\ProgramData\CitrixCseCache`
>   [...]
>   `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Citrix\GroupPolicy`
>   [..]
>   `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Citrix\GroupPolicy`

See that article for the actual process of "*deleting the policy folders on the Microsoft Domain Controller (s)*". (And regardless of what the article says: I'd still try deleting the cache *first* and see if that is enough.)